# Error: connect.compress is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, babeljs

I am helping out on a project developed [mostly] in TypeScript, then compiled to JavaScript. We have a node backend and react-native front-end. After upgrading to Babel6, project does started giving us a bunch of errors about missing modules. I was able to resolve those by adding the "missing" modules locally.
Now, I get an error exactly similar to the one reporting on github at
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4489
Please take a look:

```
ERROR  connect.compress is not a function

TypeError: connect.compress is not a function
at runServer (runServer.js:28:18)
at startServer (server.js:144:3)
at _server (server.js:140:3)
at server.js:24:5
at tryCallTwo (/Users/igorshmukler/Projects/tickmark/taxfyle-ios/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
at doResolve (/Users/igorshmukler/Projects/tickmark/taxfyle-ios/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
at new Promise (/Users/igorshmukler/Projects/tickmark/taxfyle-ios/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
at Array.server (server.js:23:10)
at run (/Users/igorshmukler/Projects/tickmark/taxfyle-ios/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:85:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/igorshmukler/Projects/tickmark/taxfyle-ios/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:162:3)

See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html
for common problems and solutions.
```

In the case referenced on github, the problem was resolved by running npm install in react-native directory. I am not sure what it means. I run install in my project directory.

Please advise if you have suggestions as to what to check etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manually register babel, node and react packages one-by-one and now everything builds until we need LinkedStateMixin from . Those are being search in an invalid directory. This is where the entire build breaks down, now. I installed this addon, much like other packages locally with

```
$npm install react-addons-linked-state-mixin
```

This apparently did not help and build is looking for it in an invalid directory -  /Users/node_modules/LinkedStateMixin

Don't know where/how to fix this, yet.